# Getting error while installing Webpack with Angular 6 project

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-webpack, angular-webpack-starter

While installing webpack with Angular6 project
I am getting error and not able to install it
I used CLI command entering into project folder named **myNewAngularPro** -

```
users-MacBook-Pro-3:myNewAngularPro user$ npm install -g webpack-cli
```

**Error I got** -:

```
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm WARN webpack-cli@3.1.0 requires a peer of webpack@^4.x.x but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!  { Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!   stack: 'Error: EACCES: permission denied, access \'/usr/local/lib/node_modules\'',
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator (though this is not recommended).

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/user/.npm/_logs/2018-09-04T10_34_48_494Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Are you running as administrator?

Comment: yes I am running as administrator

Comment: why you doing separately install webpack its already in your application if want to update then update application first thn update webpack too or 


---------just use ----------

npm i webpack

Comment: show you package json